# How to get git commit id with date

Tags: git, gitlab

I am having a big git repository and I want to temporarily test code which was 1 year back.
For that I want to get a commit Id which is 1 year old.

I need to get commit id of any commit which is made exactly 1 year back (1 day error margin is fine).

Is there any way to find out the commit id based on no. of years ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log command has the handy [`--until` / --before](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---untilltdategt) option.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h" --until="1 year ago" -1
```

should do the trick. (Use `%H` instead of `%h` if you need the long hash form)

Comment: Oh lol sorry... I meant "--before" .... thanks to Andrejs who got it right.

Comment: @Yuvraj Both syntaxes (`--before` / `--until`) work the same.

Answer (score 1):

One of many options:

```
git rev-list -1 --before="1 year ago" master
```